# Cournot Duopoly and Non existence of best response function

Tags: game-theory

Is it possible for a cournot duopoly game to not have the best response functions?

I have a profit function whose first-derivative is piece-wise. When I solve for one player's quantity (decision), it is equal to $0$. Does this mean there does not exist best response functions?

I am self-studying Game Theory and I apologize if this question is way too basic or completely wrong.

Comment: Could you provide the profit function?

Comment: The best responses exist under broad conditions (extreme value theorem) and $0$ may be a best response, but existence of the equilibrium is more demanding.